# select2 - Change configuration dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to override the `maximumSelectionLength` configuration option in `select2` dynamically if the user chose the first option, I tried to do it as follows...

```
$(".some-div select").on("select2:open", function(e) {

    if(e.target.options[0].selected) {
        $(this).select2({
           maximumSelectionLength: 1
        });
    }

});
```

But it always gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`

How can I do that?

Comment: You probably have to destroy existing select2 instance and recreate new instance with desired params.

Comment: @AniruddhJoshi I tried that, but also got the same error :(

Comment: Can you mention how are you doing that?

Comment: $(this).select2("destroy");
      $(this).select2({
       maximumSelectionLength: 1
      });

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is referencing the actual `select2` element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a native way to get items index `evt.params.data.element.index`, So
simply do this:

```
$('#example').select2({
  maximumSelectionLength: 5
});

$("#example").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
  let index = evt.params.data.element.index; // get index 
  if (index === 0) {
    $('#example').select2({ //re-init
      maximumSelectionLength: 1
    });
  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zpt8vuo/)**

You can bring back default value of `maximumSelectionLength` on `else`

Comment: It causes to lose previous configurations but couldn't find another solution too.